# How to call class method in Func()

Tags: automation, autohotkey

I can call function with Func() method like this, but how to call class method?

For exemple:

```py
class BaseClass
{
    myMethod(str)
    {
        msgbox % str
    }
}

FuncRef := Func(BaseClass.myMethod)
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you just need to enclose your `class.method` in quotes.

```
class BaseClass
{
    myMethod(str)
    {
        MsgBox % str
    }
}

f1::
FuncRef := Func( "BaseClass.myMethod" )
FuncRef.Call( _ , "yo!" )
Return
```

While I don't know why, this does now require two parameters when calling it.
Alternatively, you can call your method without using `Func()`, like so:

```
f1::BaseClass.myMethod( "yo!" )
```